# Custom CSS file not available on front end

Tags: magento2, css, magento2.4.3, parent-child-theme

I have created a child theme of parent theme, and declared default_head_blocks.xml at

<child_theme_dir>/Magento_Theme/layout folder with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
        <css src="css/custom.css" media="all"/>
        <css src="css/custom_responsive.css" media="all"/> 
    </head>
</page>
```

and created these 2 css files in directory:

<child_theme_dir>/web/css

and put my custom styles in those files, deleted all static content form pub folder, deployed static content, cleared all caches but still when I check on front end, the custom.css is not included in output, not sure what I am doing wrong while this seems to be standard process as given here ( https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-themes.html ) and I did it many times before too.

TIA

---- Added theme.xml & registration.php ---

Though personally I think they have no relation with my problem, still sharing the same, I have personally verified by making changes in other files in my child theme and the changes are getting applied

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Egon gemsone</title>
    <parent>Mgs/claue</parent>
    <media>
        <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
    </media>
</theme>
```

registration.php file

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/Egon/gemsone',
    __DIR__
);
```

Comment: did you apply your child theme from admin panel? if not goto content->configuration->edit theme and apply your child theme from dropdown.

Comment: yes I did it, initially it was for Store view only, but later on I even tried applying it to website and globally also.

Comment: run s:di:compile or kindly share your theme.xml and registration.php from your theme.

Comment: I already ran all commands like s:upgrade, s:di:compile , s:static-content:deploy , cleared all caches, still as per your message I edited the question and placed theme.xml & registration.php file

Comment: try to remove media tag from your css source tag and then try run all comands
like this <css src="css/custom.css"/>

Comment: tried removing media tag but no difference

Answer (score 0):

you have an issue with your **default_head_blocks.xml** do like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/custom.css" /> 
    </head>
</page>
```

Comment: Already tried that before posting question, as tried again but it didn't work :(

Comment: same thing working for me, i dont know whats wrong with your scenario, let me sent you a complete extended theme so you can try this.

Comment: and where do you place your child theme kindly share path.

Comment: download extended theme from here https://drive.google.com/file/d/179WawRqPQ7nmuH7qc8zedZADp6IiGU2Z/view

Comment: Sorry for responding late, was not available, thanks for all your efforts, I used your files as it is and ran all magento commands still no luck, not sure what's wrong with my environment, as I have done this many times before this is first time I am facing such issue

Comment: i can further debug it for you in a chat if you want.

Comment: Sure let me know your available time in IST, we can discuss on chat

Comment: Please let me know your available time

Comment: we can chat same time tomorow.

Comment: ok Sure see you at 9:00 PM IST

Comment: Though not a good way but I managed to get CSS added on front end, I created a cutom module and created a new default_head_blocks.xml in that custom module and included my css from there and it started showing, seems like theme has some issues in processing that xml, but anyways shall work for me for the time, thanks a lot for your support and time, enjoy our weekend. :)